# JHipster 6.0 chunk.js error in user-management

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jhipster

I am running beta version of JHipster (6.0) to be able to use Java 11.

I have next error when I am trying to open

user-management tab (code without Java or js changes after generation, only libs).

Here is a link to this project and npm modules directory in two separate archives [gdrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kOXENajAbfdyKNvgDGxzv5-Duxuw4wPL/view?usp=sharing)

```
NavigationStart {id: 5, url: "/admin/user-management", navigationTrigger: "imperative", restoredState: null}
    platform-browser.js?6588:216 Router Event: RouteConfigLoadStart
    platform-browser.js?6588:211 RouteConfigLoadStart(path: admin)
    platform-browser.js?6588:211 RouteConfigLoadStart {route: {…}}
    main.bundle.js:829 GET http://localhost:8080/app/0.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
    requireEnsure @ main.bundle.js:829
    fn.e @ main.bundle.js:156
    (anonymous) @ app-routing.module.ts?136b:14
    ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js?d135:910
    loadChildren @ app-routing.module.ts?136b:14
    RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory @ router.js?6580:3617
    RouterConfigLoader.load @ router.js?6580:3602
    (anonymous) @ router.js?6580:2605
    MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js?a6c5:61
    MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js?a6c5:51
    Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js?1453:53
    (anonymous) @ scalar.js?3d4f:5
    Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:43
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:29
    MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js?a6c5:29
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:24
    MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js?a6c5:29
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:24
    CatchOperator.call @ catchError.js?f59d:18
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:24
    (anonymous) @ subscribeTo.js?1716:21
    subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js?ce8b:11
    MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js?a6c5:74
    MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js?a6c5:68
    MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js?a6c5:51
    Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js?1453:53
    MapSubscriber._next @ map.js?ebb6:41
    Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js?1453:53
    (anonymous) @ subscribeToArray.js?fad2:5
    Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:43
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:29
    MapOperator.call @ map.js?ebb6:18
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:24
    MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js?a6c5:29
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:24
    FilterOperator.call @ filter.js?5670:15
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:24
    TakeOperator.call @ take.js?b7d7:24
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:24
    DoOperator.call @ tap.js?c4cc:18
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:24
    CatchOperator.call @ catchError.js?f59d:18
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:24
    MapOperator.call @ map.js?ebb6:18
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:24
    (anonymous) @ subscribeTo.js?1716:21
    subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js?ce8b:11
    MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js?a6c5:74
    MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js?a6c5:68
    MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js?a6c5:51
    Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js?1453:53
    (anonymous) @ scalar.js?3d4f:5
    Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:43
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:29
    MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js?a6c5:29
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:24
    TakeLastOperator.call @ takeLast.js?0318:24
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:24
    DoOperator.call @ tap.js?c4cc:18
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:24
    MapOperator.call @ map.js?ebb6:18
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:24
    MapOperator.call @ map.js?ebb6:18
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:24
    MapOperator.call @ map.js?ebb6:18
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:24
    CatchOperator.call @ catchError.js?f59d:18
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:24
    MapOperator.call @ map.js?ebb6:18
    Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js?e9b9:24
    (anonymous) @ subscribeTo.js?1716:21
    subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js?ce8b:11
    SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub @ switchMap.js?d792:51
    SwitchMapSubscriber._next @ switchMap.js?d792:41
    Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js?1453:53
    SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext @ switchMap.js?d792:72
    InnerSubscriber._next @ InnerSubscriber.js?acf8:15
    Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js?1453:53
    (anonymous) @ subscribeToPromise.js?4b95:7
    ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js?d135:391
    onInvoke @ core.js?09c9:17298
    ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js?d135:390
    Zone.run @ zone.js?d135:150
    (anonymous) @ zone.js?d135:889
    ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js?d135:423
    onInvokeTask @ core.js?09c9:17289
    ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js?d135:422
    Zone.runTask @ zone.js?d135:195
    drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js?d135:601
    ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js?d135:502
    invokeTask @ zone.js?d135:1744
    globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js?d135:1770
    Show 62 more frames
    platform-browser.js?6588:216 Router Event: NavigationError
    platform-browser.js?6588:211 NavigationError(id: 5, url: '/admin/user-management', error: [object Object])
    platform-browser.js?6588:211 NavigationError {id: 5, url: "/admin/user-management", error: {…}}
    core.js?09c9:15723 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Object: {"loadChunkError":true,"details":{"type":"error","request":"http://localhost:8080/app/0.chunk.js"}}
    at resolvePromise (zone.js?d135:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js?d135:788)
    at eval (zone.js?d135:892)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js?d135:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js?09c9:17289)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js?d135:422)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js?d135:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js?d135:601)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js?d135:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js?d135:1744)
```

Here is my POM [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/USPaFa9A)

Comment: Posted after npm start. npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --inline --hot --port=9060 --watch-content-base --env.stats=minimal ------> can not access even login page --- log https://pastebin.com/XajutWR5

Comment: Looks like you're accessing your app on port 8080 (see error) while you should access it at port 9060 through webpack dev server. Please show also how you run the build that fails in pastebin. Also explain what you mean by "only libs". Are you new to JHipster?

Comment: no-no, I logged in using 9060, 8080 it is just in error in js. Thnx! @Gaël

Comment: OK but the js app should never access port 8080 when running from port 9060, because all static contents is served by webpack and all API calls are proxified by webpack dev server (see proxy.conf.json)

Comment: @GaëlMarziou thnx very much! What could probably solve this? Here is this project and npm modules dir separately https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZkJJs-thB5d6GQHyW-h6x5PdBNc_OvUT/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kOXENajAbfdyKNvgDGxzv5-Duxuw4wPL/view?usp=sharing I am asking for help just bacause it still hard to start using Java >8. Looks like java troubles solved for me, but now this js issue...